# Como leer respuesta xml en Groovy

Tags: java, script, groovy, jdeveloper

Hola me encuentro ejecutando una solicitud wsdl SOAP en Groovy y al leer el archivo y navegar en el no lee el cuerpo del response como quiero, almenos es lo que creo.

He aquí el código:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.soap.*
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlParser

def client = new SOAPClient('http://192.5..../.../aservice_login.aspx?wsdl')
    
def response = client.send("""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mid="Canal">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mid:service_login.Execute>
         <mid:Applicationname>YT12052022MAY</mid:Applicationname>
         <mid:Apikey>123456789</mid:Apikey>
      </mid:service_login.Execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
""")
def codigo = response.text

return "Respuesta: \n ${codigo}"
```

La respuesta seria esta al ejecutar la solicitud en SOAP UI:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <service_login.ExecuteResponse xmlns="Canal">
         <Apptoken>Token_ejemplo</Apptoken>
         <Expirydate>2022-05-13</Expirydate>
         <Resultcode>OK000</Resultcode>
         <Message>Conexion exitosa</Message>
      </service_login.ExecuteResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

He intentado consumir este servicio y llegarle a los campos con estas acciones...

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(codigo)
assert xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'service_login.ExecuteResponse'.Resultcode.text == 'OK000'
```

Pero me arroja este error:
Assertion failed:

```
assert xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'service_login.ExecuteResponse'.Resultcode.text == 'OK000'
| | | | | |
| | | | [] false
| | | [{Canal}Resultcode[attributes={}; value=[OK000]]]
| | [{Canal}service_login.ExecuteResponse[attributes={}; value=[{Canal}Apptoken[attributes={}; value=[EAAAALxNrEA7928VqQI9WeKezInFr5sSAoptMJD/cUiCMFo/Yhmk3sCUDnu/aFtwd/k3qfGs9D84U+C54TG8PfD+la8=]], {Canal}Expirydate[attributes={}; value=[2022-05-17]], {Canal}Resultcode[attributes={}; value=[OK000]], {Canal}Message[attributes={}; value=[Conexion exitosa]]]]]
```

Si alguien conoce como resolver y llegarle a los atributos, se los agradecere muchisimo....
Soy nuevo en Groovy :D

Answer (score 0):

Cambie el cuerpo del código y decidí leer la respuesta por individual de cada campo retornado y luego reemplazar la cadena que retornaba, eliminando lo que no me interesa del string y claro esto es mapeando la respuesta.

Dejo el codigo por si a alguien le puede servir este tipo de solucion...

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.soap.*
import groovy.xml.XmlParser

def client = new SOAPClient('http://192.5.../.../aservice_login.aspx?wsdl')
    
def response = client.send("""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mid="Canal">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mid:service_login.Execute>
         <mid:Applicationname>YT12052022MAY</mid:Applicationname>
         <mid:Apikey>123456789</mid:Apikey>
      </mid:service_login.Execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
""")

def codigo = response.text

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(codigo)
def ResultCode = xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'service_login.ExecuteResponse'.Resultcode.toString()
def AppToken = xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'service_login.ExecuteResponse'.Apptoken.toString()
def ExpiryDate = xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'service_login.ExecuteResponse'.Expirydate.toString()

//Este es lo que retorna por cada atributo
//[{Canal}Apptoken[attributes={}; value=['TokenRetorno']]]

AppToken = AppToken.replace("[{Canal}Apptoken[attributes={}; value=[","").replace("]]]","")
ResultCode = ResultCode.replace("[{Canal}Resultcode[attributes={}; value=[","").replace("]]]","")
ExpiryDate = ExpiryDate.replace("[{Canal}Expirydate[attributes={}; value=[","").replace("]]]","")

return "Codigo: ${ResultCode} \nTokken: ${AppToken} \nExpiryDate: ${ExpiryDate}"
```

Saludos...